# How to check if a value is unique in a specific pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, unique

I need to check if a specific value exists multiple times in a pandas dataframe column. This is the basic code;

```
for index, row in df_x.iterrows():
    try:
        if row[1] in df_y['b'].values:  

# if row[1] exists in df_y i want to know how many time is it repeated, or if it is unique or not

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error ', e)
```

Comment: Have you looked into `df_y['b'].value_counts()`?

Comment: I tried v_counts = df['Column Name'].value_counts() but could't know how to check if row1 exists and how many times

Comment: what's the output of `v_counts[your_values]` ?

Answer (score 7):

You've a DataFrame named by df
So you want to know a specific column named by "spec_col" contains unique values

```
import pandas as pd

pd.Series(df["spec_col"]).is_unique
>>> True
```

Comment: I guess the conversion to `pd.Series` is not even necessary, so `df['spec_col'].is_unique` would already work?

Answer (score 2):

Pandas is there to help you avoid for-loops. Pandas offers dozen of functionality to help you with that

E.g.

```py
import pandas as pd

# data

df = pd.DataFrame({'uni':[1,2,3,4],'not_uni':[2,2,1,3]})

# value_counts

print(df['uni'].value_counts())
print(df['not_uni'].value_counts())
```

This will count the values. Unique values will have have if 1, will non unique will have value greater than 1.

[image]

As you can see in uni column we only have 1, as there is no repeated value, will in not_uni column we have 2 that is repeated twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you care specifically about how many times the value in the first row appears:

```py
np.random.seed(2)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.rand(10) // .1,
                    'b':np.random.rand(10) // .01,
                    'c':np.random.choice(['A','B','C', 'D', 'E'], 10)})
df['c'].value_counts()[df.loc[0,'c']]
```

`df`:

```
     a     b  c
0  7.0  11.0  B
1  5.0  14.0  D
2  1.0  85.0  A
3  3.0  50.0  C
4  4.0  21.0  B
5  6.0  99.0  E
6  7.0  31.0  A
7  6.0  25.0  B
8  6.0  80.0  B
9  9.0  35.0  B
```

`df['c'].value_counts()[df.loc[0,'c']]` returns `5` (non-unique), whereas 
`df['c'].value_counts()[df.loc[5,'c']]` returns `1`. You may need to add some exception handling in case the row you are trying to look up is `np.nan`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Series`/`Dataframe` method `isin` followed by a `sum` to count the number of occurences.

With your example:

```py
for index, row in df_x.iterrows():
    try:
        count = df_y['b'].isin([row[1]]).sum()
        print("df_y['b'] contains {} times the value {}".format(count, row[1])) 

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error ', e)
```

However that is not really efficient since you are going to iterate through the `b` column of `df_y` for each value of `row[1]`.

First, you could do a `unique` in the parent column to avoid counting multiple time the same value, second using something with `value_counts` would avoid a lot of loops. You could make your question a bit more clear so we can know exactly what you are after as it is not really clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will give you repeated values in column `col`:

```
list(df["col"].value_counts()[df["col"].value_counts() > 1].index)
```

Comment: could you check the answer @ aruydzi1?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same, but I suppose there are better ways, like first cleaning and altering your pandas dataframe better.

Anyway, here is my solution

`np.sum(df[df['col_name'] == value]['col_name'].value_counts())`

This gives you the count of the repeated values (***value***) in column ***col_name***.